# How can i forbid an app showing its notification in Android?

Tags: android

we know we can through the setting->application->(click an app)->(tick)show notification to allow or forbid the application's notification.

now i want to make an app to list all the application that were installed in my phone and show it was forbid or allow notification.

I through google know about PackageManager API, but it can only get the information of an app.

My question is, **how i can get notification setting?**

Answer (score 0):

There is no API to query the 'Show notification' setting or change it programmatically so unfortunately this is not possible.